# iOS 14 gives "OS Error: Bad file descriptor, errno = 9" when doing local network broadcasting

Tags: flutter, udp, multicast, ios14

Doing a little [Jeopardy style Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) here.

I'm developing an app in Flutter that uses [the udp package](https://pub.dev/packages/udp) for broadcasting on the local network. This has worked fine on Android, Windows, macOS and iOS until I tried on an iOS 14.6 device.

The code flow is mainly like this:

```
var endPoint = Endpoint.broadcast(port: Port(6000));
var udpFuture = UDP.bind(Endpoint.any(port: Port(6000)));
udpFuture.then((udp) {
   udp.listen((datagram) {
       handleMessage(datagram.data);
   });
   udp.send(bytesToSend, endPoint);
}
```

The error message I'm getting is this: `Unhandled Exception: OS Error: Bad file descriptor, errno = 9`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 14 your app needs the Multicast networking entitlement [`com.apple.developer.networking.multicast`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_networking_multicast) to be able to send or receive IP multicast traffic.

To get the entitlement you need to [apply using Apple's request form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/networking-multicast). It took me 4-5 days before I got the request approved.

Then you can follow [the instructions on Apple's forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663271) to get up and running.