# Is it enough to add entitlements manually?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, entitlements

I need to add networking multicast entitlement to my Flutter app. At least that what I *think* I need to do according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862903/ios-14-gives-os-error-bad-file-descriptor-errno-9-when-doing-local-network/69862904#69862904).

> Starting from iOS 14 your app needs the Multicast networking
> entitlement com.apple.developer.networking.multicast to be able to
> send or receive IP multicast traffic.
>
> To get the entitlement you need to apply using Apple's request form.
> It took me 4-5 days before I got the request approved.
>
> Then you can follow the instructions on Apple's forums to get up and
> running.

Before I fill in the form, I want to know if adding the entitlement to the `Runner.entitlements` file is enough. I have no access to XCode. (Or do I have to add them to `Info.plist`?)

Thank you.

Comment: The entitlement needs to be added to your provisioning profile in the Apple developer portal. You can't add the entitlement until Apple has approved it and made it available to add to your provisioning profile. If you add the entitlement manually to your entitlements plist then you will get a code signing failure because the entitlements file does not match the provisioning profile.

Comment: Thank you, If you add this as an answer I can accept it